# Three unknown keywords and an equation

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay

- *Die Disk* = Movie Franchise + Storage device.
- *Digital Peaks* = AI Technology + Television Series.
- *Equatorial Pig* = Country + Animal.

---

- Keyword of *Die Disk* is *Hard*.
- Keyword of *Digital Peaks* is *Twin*.
- Keyword of *Equatorial Pig* is *Guinea*.

---

- *A* = Oscar Winning Actress + Retired Professional Wrestler.
- *B* = Former Rock Band + Fantasy Creature.
- *C* = Geoffrey MacCormack + Flowering Plant.

---

- Keyword of *A* is *X*.
- Keyword of *B* is *Y*.
- Keyword of *C* is *Z*.

---

- *P* + *Q* = *R* where *P*, *Q* and *R* are the three members in a group of seven.

---

- (*P* + *X*) is found in Wyoming, USA.
- (*Q* + *Y*) is found in Washington, USA.
- (*R* + *Z*) is found in Amsterdam, Netherlands.

---

***Identify (A, B, C), (X, Y, Z) and (P, Q, R).***

Answer (score 4):

> (A, B, C) = (Emma Cold, Big Dwarf, Warren Lily)
>  (X, Y, Z) = (Stone, Mountain, Peace)
>  (P, Q, R) = (Yellow, Blue, Green)

And the full thought process as in the original post:

> Emma Cold Steve Austin = Oscar Winning Actress + Retired Professional Wrestler.
>  Big Dwarf = Former Rock Band + Fantasy Creature.
>  Warren Lily = Geoffrey MacCormack + Flowering Plant.

> Keyword of Emma Cold Steve Austin is Stone.
>  Keyword of Big Dwarf is Mountain.
>  Keyword of Warren Lily is Peace.

> Yellow + Blue = Green, the three members of the rainbow.

> Yellowstone is a national park found in Wyoming, USA.
>  Blue Mountain is a mountain found in Washington, USA.
>  Greenpeace is headquartered in Amsterdam, Netherlands.

I was not sure about:

> Blue Mountain, but Mountain Dwarf (and Elf) are common fantasy creatures particularly in tabletop games I'm familiar with, but Big Mountain was a bit of a stretch.

Comment: I agree with most of this, but I'm not 100% sure about rot13(ovt zbhagnva) fitting the clue for "former rock band" as it's neither former nor a rock band.

Comment: I was wavering it could just be rot13(Zbhagnva), and B just rot13(Qjnes).

Comment: Most of the answer is spot on except for B. The one you've mentioned is not a 'former' rock band as @Surma points out. Hence the keyword Y also changes along with Q+Y. See if you can find another one that fits.

Comment: Thanks! Struggling to come up with anything else but not giving up.